# Get Page URL after Ajax call has been made

Tags: ajax, url

I am using a ajax call to update page content and update the URL accordingly. I have share buttons on the page and when I want to share the whole page I only receive the previous loaded URL.

So as an example -

```
http://localhost/labs/category/best-of-the-best-campaign/
```

is my current loaded URL. When I do a Ajax call

```
http://localhost/labs/tag/ecommerce/?catid=2
```

This is the new URL. But when I share the page I still get the previous loaded URL. which is

```
http://localhost/labs/category/best-of-the-best-campaign
```

Could anyone point to me what might be going wrong?

```
<?php echo $url="http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";?>
```

This is what I'm using to get the current URL of the page. I have a doubt that it might be due to the server request but I am not entirely sure about it and how I might change it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reinitialize the `$url variable` after `ajax call`

You can write `php code` in your `ajax sucess function` like,

```
<script>
    ......// your code
    success:function()
    {
       // your code
       <?php 
          $url="http://localhost/labs/tag/ecommerce/?catid=2";
          and use it.
       ?>
    }
    ......// your code
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply.. I figured it out with a help of a friend :)     

Got the href attribute of each of the share buttons and then added the changed url to the end of it. Worked like a charm. Thanks for the replies and help :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `location.href` to get the url of the current page in JavaScript?